# Populating listview control passing parameters to constructor from another form

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I need to populate a listview control on Takenshows.cs form, passing parameters to constructor from Main.cs form.

When I'm running the code, the listview is empty. I don't know what is wrong with my code.

Here's the main.cs form on button when I'm sending parameters to Takenshows.cs form:

```
shows = new Takenshows(Ordnumber,meddt, values, 
   num);
```

And this is the Takenshows.cs form:

```
      int Ordnum;
      string medDateTime;
      string val;
      int number;
          public Takenshows()
             {
                InitializeComponent();
               }

          public Takenshows(int Ordnumber, string 
                  dtmed, string values, int num)
               {
        
                  Ordnum = Ordnumber;
                  medDateTime = dtmed;
                  val = values;
                  number = num;
                  InitializeComponent();
               }
```

I know the problem is on Takenshows_load, but I don't know why listview doesn't fill.

```
     private void Takenshows_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


             for(int i=0; i< listView1.Items.Count; i++){
                         
                         listView1.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text = Ordnum.ToString();
                         listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text = medDateTime;
                         listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text = val;
                         listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text = number.ToString();

                         ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[0].Text); 
                         item.SubItems.Add(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text);
                         item.SubItems.Add(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[2].Text);        
                         item.SubItems.Add(listView1.Items[i].SubItems[3].Text);
                         listView1.Items.Add(item);
                     } 



                             }

        private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

                }
```

Anything can I do to fix this issue?

By certain this is Main.cs form:

```
 public partial class Main : Form
{
           int Ordnumber;
           string meddt;
           string values;
           int num;
           TakenShows shows;

     public Main()
           {
        InitializeComponent();
             }

      private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
        Ordnumber = GetOrdNumberLN.getInstance().GettingOrdNumber();
        Ordnumber = Ordnumber + 1;
        meddt = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        num = GetNumberLN.getInstance().GettingNumber();
        values = textBox_F.Text + " " + textBox_PT.Text + " " + textBox_QT.Text 
        shows = new Takenshows(Ordnumber,meddt, values, 
   num);
        shows.Show();


          }
```

Comment: How many items `listView1` already has when the Form is created?  -- Why are you trying set the same values to all Items (if you actually have any in there) while trying to create a new Items that repeat the same values, taken from an existing Item instead of using the actual values? -- A description of the initial state of your ListView and what should happen when the Form is loaded, may help to clarify your intentions

Comment: Why are you looping here? Just create `var item = new ListViewItem(Ordnum.ToString());`, add the subitems, `item.SubItems.Add(medDateTime);`, do the same to add `val` and `number`, then add the new item to collection, `listView1.Items.Add(item);`. That's it. Maybe you need to pass a `List<T>` where `T` encapsulates `Ordnumber,meddt, values, 
   num` properties?

Comment: I don't know how results the code. I need help.

Comment: Sure. but we need to understand what you are trying to do. Do you add any `ListViewItem` objects by the designer? When you say _Populating listview_, do you mean adding one item or many? If the later then we need a context from the `main` Form. Please try to elaborate...

Comment: I do what you said me but listview shows only one item. I need the listview shows each item I add when I press the button takes me to TakenShows.cs form. And I don't know how I pass List<T> where T encapsulates Ordnumber, meddt, values, num properties. I've been watching tutorials but there is no way. I don't know which is the solution to this problem.

Comment: No problem, can you post some relevant code from the `main` form so we can understand the context...?

Comment: I'm trying to adding one item to listview every time I'm pressing "take shows" button and by each time I'm pressing this button, listview will show all items. The solution you've passed me only works for one item. I need when I press the button, the listview adds one item. I press the button once again and listview adds another item again. And so with the others.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248333/discussion-between-francisco-arias-and-dr-null).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep the data you create in some collection container such as `DataTable` or `List<T>` to be able to set/get/manipulate the collected items. Here's a `List<T>` implementation example.

- Switch to the Solution Explorer window and select your project.
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to open the *Add New Item* dialog.
- Rename the class to `ShowItem.cs` and hit the *Add* button.

Edit the class as follows:

```cs
public class ShowItem
{
    public ShowItem() { }

    // Find better names...
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public int OrderNumber { get; set; }
    public DateTime MedDate { get; set; }
    public string F { get; set; }
    public string PT { get; set; }
    public string QT { get; set; }
    public string Values => $"{F} {PT} {QT}";
}
```

Now you have the `ShowItem` type to create instances from it and keep them in a  `List<ShowItem>`.

In case you want to show modal dialog, edit the `Main` Form as follows:

```cs
// +
using System.Collections.Generic;
// ...

public partial class Main : Form
{
    private readonly List<ShowItem> showItems;

    public Main()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        showItems = new List<ShowItem>();
    }

    // Find a better name...
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var show = new ShowItem
        {
            OrderNumber = GetOrdNumberLN.getInstance().GettingOrdNumber() + 1,
            MedDate = DateTime.Now,
            Number = GetNumberLN.getInstance().GettingNumber(),
            F = textBox_F.Text,
            PT = textBox_PT.Text,
            QT = textBox_QT.Text
        };

        showItems.Add(show);

        using (var frm = new Takenshows(showItems))
        {
            frm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

... and the `Takenshows` Form:

```cs
// +
using System.Linq;
// ...

public partial class Takenshows : Form
{
    public Takenshows()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public Takenshows(IEnumerable<ShowItem> items) : this()
    {
        AddItems(items);
    }

    internal void AddItem(ShowItem item) => AddItems(new[] { item });

    internal void AddItems(IEnumerable<ShowItem> items)
    {
        var lvis = items.Select(x => new ListViewItem(new[]
        {
            x.OrderNumber.ToString(),
            x.MedDate.ToString(),
            x.Values,
            x.Number.ToString()
        }));
        listView1.Items.AddRange(lvis.ToArray());
    }
}
```

In contrast, if you need to keep the `Takenshows` Form open, then edit the `button2_Click` event handler in `Main` as shown below. Note, the access modifier of the `AddItem` and `AddItems` methods is `internal` for this scenario.

```cs
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var show = new ShowItem
    {
        OrderNumber = GetOrdNumberLN.getInstance().GettingOrdNumber() + 1,
        MedDate = DateTime.Now,
        Number = GetNumberLN.getInstance().GettingNumber(),
        F = textBox_F.Text,
        PT = textBox_PT.Text,
        QT = textBox_QT.Text
    };

    showItems.Add(show);

    var frm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Takenshows>().FirstOrDefault();

    if (frm == null)
    {
        frm = new Takenshows(showItems);
        frm.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        frm.AddItem(show);
        frm.Activate();
    }            
}
```

Hope this helps you to take-off.