# Register showItems in Database from Main form

Tags: c#

This post is related to [Populating listview control passing parameters to constructor from another form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73841807/populating-listview-control-passing-parameters-to-constructor-from-another-form/73845753#73845753)

Now I need to save items in database. I'm using SQL server as engine database and c# as Language's programming.

Based in answers about the related post I've mentioned at the top from this post, I was doing the functions to get all items of showlistitems from TakenShows.cs but something is wrong with the code.

First able, this is the Main.cs form

```
   public partial class Main : Form
             {
         private readonly List<ShowItem> showItems;
             private List<ShowItem> getItems;

            public Main()
                      {
                   InitializeComponent();
                 showItems = new List<ShowItem>();
                 getItems = new List<ShowItem>();
                 }

          // Button save items

         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
    

                 var shows = new Takenshows(showItems);

               getItems = shows.receiveItems();

  
        foreach(var x in getItems)
        {
            // Query saving items in database. 
         SaveItemsLN.getInstance().SaveItems(x.OrderNumber, x.MedDate, x.Values, x.Number);
     
          }


  FinishPracticeLN.getInstance().PracticeToFinish(); 

       //TakenShows form should be closed when I click on save items button after getting all items from listview control and it doesn't happen          

               shows.Close();
               Close();

          }
           
           //button add items

         private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
       
          int OrdNum = GetOrdNumberLN.getInstance().GettingOrdNumber();

            var show = new ShowItem
          //I fix the value assigned to OrderNumber because I have to avoid duplicates keys on Item table.
     {
         OrderNumber = OrdNum + showItems.Count + 1,
         MedDate = DateTime.Now,
         F = textBox_F.Text,
         PT = textBox_PT.Text,
         QT = textBox_QT.Text,
         Number = GetNumberLN.getInstance().GettingNumber(),
         };

         showItems.Add(show);

         var frm = Application.OpenForms.OfType<Takenshows>().FirstOrDefault();

       if (frm == null)
           {
            frm = new Takenshows(showItems);
            frm.Show();
            }
            else
            {
             frm.AddItem(show);
             frm.Activate();
              }            
               }

           }
```

When I save items in database, Takenshows form should close and not be opened yet after I click on 'save items' button.

Now this is Takenshows.cs Form when I use the functions to show and save items.

```
      public partial class Takenshows : Form
              {

                public Takenshows()
                    {
                     InitializeComponent();
                     receiveItems();
                      }
              public Takenshows(IEnumerable<ShowItem> items) : this()
                 {
                    AddItems(items);
                             }
         //This method should return a List of type ShowItem that will allow me save the items in database since Main.cs form

       public List<ShowItem> receiveItems(){

        List<ShowItem> items;
        try
        {
           //Here's the issue (error). On this line code. Cannot cast. Why?
                  //How can fix this issue?

            items = listView1.Items.Cast<ShowItem>().ToList();

                   return items;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }

        }

            internal void AddItem(ShowItem item) => AddItems(new[] { item });

         internal void AddItems(IEnumerable<ShowItem> items)
              {
               var lvis = items.Select(x => new ListViewItem(new[]
     {
        x.OrderNumber.ToString(),
        x.MedDate.ToString(),
        x.Values,
        x.Number.ToString()
    })); 

        listView1.Items.AddRange(lvis.ToArray());
    }


  private void Takenshows_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      

    }
          private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {

            }


         }

      }
```

When I click on save items button, application throws me an exception says "Cannot cast a List of datatype  to ". that is the code not works.

How can I do fix these issues? Has anyone the answer to fix the issues?

Comment: I must get all Items from listview it's in Takenshows.cs form and save them in my database. The method to save the items is called inside a loop foreach in Main.cs form when I click on button 1. The button 1 is called "save items"

Answer (score 1):

It's done. All I had to do was to modificate the structure of the stored procedure and column of the Items table on database, replacing varchar by varchar(max).

Then in Takenshows.cs defined the next one method:

```
              public List<ShowList> returnItems(List<ShowList> items){

        return items;
         }
```

In Main.cs on save items button (button1)

```
        receiveItems = new Takenshows().returnItems(showItems);


                  foreach (var x in receiveItems)
         {
             
          SaveItemsLN.getInstance().SaveItems(x.OrderNumber, x.MedDate, x.Values, x.Number);
         }
```

I hope my own answer will serve to someone who needs solve difficult issues like is from this post.